# IBrowse and persistent connection per client process

Tags: http, erlang, persistent

I need to operate with a SOAP service from Erlang. SOAP implementation is not a subject, I have a problem with HTTP requests at a client side.

I use IBrowse as a HTTP client. This SOAP service uses a specific authorization mechanism, which relates an opened session to a client connection (socket). So, the client should use only one persistent connection to server (socket), and if it try to send a request via another socket (e.g., connection from pool) - authorization will fail.

I use IBrowse in this way:

1. Spawn connection process to server (`ibrowse:spawn_worker_process/1`)
2. Send request to server via spawned process with `{max_sessions, 1}` and `{max_pipeline_size, 0}`.

If I understand the docs right, this should use one socket for server connection with disabled pipelining, also, I use `Connection: Keep-Alive` header and HTTP version explicitly set to 1.0. But my connection is always closed after the response is received.

How can I use IBrowse (or another http-client) the way I described above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could that with `hackney` by [reusing a connection](https://github.com/benoitc/hackney#reuse-a-connection).

Also [`gun` is quite nice http](https://github.com/extend/gun)  client, easy to use, keeping connection, but with little less connection control.